# How much choice does a linear or well-order on cardinals imply?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is well-known that if the natural (partial) order on the class of cardinal numbers is a linear order, then it is in fact a well-order and the axiom of choice holds. I was, however, interested in how much choice we can recover given *some* linear ordering, or better — a well-ordering — of the class of cardinals.

I couldn't figure out by myself any results, but I would imagine it at least implies that there are no amorphous sets.

Are there any results known about this? To be more specific, let me ask the following question:

> Is the axiom of countable choice implied by the existence of a linear ordering on the class of all cardinals? How about the existence of a well-order on this class?

Thanks in advance for all the feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

In Cohen's first model, as constructed over $L$, you have a uniform linear ordering of the entire model. However the axiom of countable choice fails: there is a Dedekind-finite set of reals.

To see that the first claim holds, note that the model is $L(A)$ where $A$ is the of generic Cohen reals. Therefore there is a surjection from $[A]^{<\omega}\times\sf Ord$ onto $L(A)$, and that defines a linear ordering on the entire universe. In particular on the class of cardinals.

(*Remark:* I am not claiming that the order extends the order of the cardinals, but it does order the class of cardinals (which is $\omega$, the $\aleph$ numbers and the Scott cardinals) in a linear order. Whether or not there is an order extension of the usual order to a linear order, I cannot say. I suspect this is the case in Cohen's model, though. Note it cannot be extended to a well-ordering since there are infinite decreasing chains.)

Comment: That seems to do the question with linear order. I suppose this can't be modified to answer the question of well-ordering of cardinals implying countable choice.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know about that. I'd be surprised if you can well-order something like the cardinals; but not surprised enough to be shocked.

Comment: But is the linear order well defined with respect to equinumerosity? You would need that to have a linear order on cardinals.

Comment: @Joel: Of course not. That would imply choice. Or am I misunderstanding you? As far as I can understand the question it asks for a linear or well order on the class of cardinals. Not an extension of the usual order to a total or well order. The latter, by the way is perhaps impossible altogether.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I am a bit baffled by the downvote.

Comment: You have a linear order on the sets, not on the cardinals.  The cardinals are equinumerosity classes of the cardinals. So we need a linear order on the sets that is well-defined with respect to equinumerosity. (I am confused by your "of course not" remark, since the OP's question here is exactly whether the existence of such a linear order implies AC.) If your linear order is not well-defined with respect to equinumerosity, then I don't see how you have an order on the cardinals.

Comment: @Joel: I think this touches a deeper question. What are cardinals? For me they are the aleph numbers and Scott cardinals. These are all sets, and they get linearly ordered with the rest of the universe.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. The point should be that if you can linearly order the universe at all, then you define a new linear order, which does respect equinumerosity. Namely, put the Scott cardinals in order (since as you say they are sets, definable representatives for each equinumerosity class), and then order within each equinumerosity class by the original order.  In this way, you arrive at the kind of linear order I had wanted. (And in particular, this doesn't imply choice.)

Comment: @Joel: So you merely want to extend the order. I actually suspect this is possible here, but I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Intention of my question was, to be more precise, to talk about a preorder $\leq$ on the class of all sets such that $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$ both hold iff $a,b$ are equinumerous, and such that induced partial order on quotient of class of sets under equicardinality is linear or well-order. If I'm not mistaken, this is equivalent to possibility of linearly/well-ordering all Scott cardinals, respectively, hence Asaf's answer does answer my boxed question (or at least the part about linear order).

Comment: @Wojowu: But that already implies choice. So the question is entirely uninteresting. That is one of the main theorems of basic set theory. If every two sets are comparable in the cardinality order then the axiom of choice holds. I expected you to know this, which is why I interpreted the question as the broader, nicer, question about orders which are not "exactly the order on the cardinals".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't require "$a\leq b$ implies $a$ has cardinality at most $b$". I only require "$a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$ implies $a$ has the same cardinality as $b$". So you did interpret my question correctly.

Comment: @Wojowu: Oh, okay then. Very good. Carry on.

Comment: @AsafKaragila How does one get the linear order of $V$ from the surjection $[A]^{<\omega}\times\mathrm{Ord}\to V$? (For example, if $P$ is a partition of $A$, why is there a linear order of $P$? And then it seems that would have to be done uniformly in $P$, but it doesn't seem obvious anyway for just a given partition.)