# What choice we can get from stipulating an extending well order on the Scott cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

The following question is similar to [that one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228040/how-much-choice-does-a-linear-or-well-order-on-cardinals-imply), but it adds some features not included in that question.

Working in $\sf ZF+ Classes$, if we axiomatize the existence of a well order on the class of all cardinals that extends the usual $\leqslant$ relation on cardinals, would that enact any form of Choice? And what is that form?

$\sf ZF + Classes$, a conservative extension of $\sf ZF$, adds another sort (upper case representing *classes*) to the original language of $\sf ZF$ (lower case standing for *sets*); write all axioms of $\sf ZF-Ext$ in lower case; axiomatize that classes are extensional; sets are classes; elements are sets, and free construction of classes after formulas in lower case. Formally:

*Axioms*

**Sorting:** $ \exists X : X=y$

**Membership:** $ X \in Y \to \exists z: X=z$

**Extensionality:** $\forall A \, \forall B: \forall x \, (x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B) \to A=B $

**Comprehension:** $
\big {(}\exists X \, \forall y \, (y \in X \leftrightarrow \phi) \big{)}$; where $\phi$ written in lower case.

**Set axioms:** all axioms of $\sf ZF-Ext$ written in lower case.

**Well ordering cardinals:** $\exists R: R\text { is a well order on} \operatorname {Card} \land \leqslant \, \subseteq R  $

Where $\operatorname {Card} $ is the class of all Scott cardinals; "$\leqslant$" is the usual order on cardinals.

A related question is the same one but about when we weaken the last axiom to *linear* ordering?

Comment: If a relation extends to a well-order, it must be well-founded. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1634372/127263) for a related question.

Comment: I would understand "written in lower case" to imply that class parameters (in particular the well-ordering $R$) are not allowed.  Or did you mean only to prohibit quantification of class variables?

Comment: @AndreasBlass, I meant the first!